# How to have webpage before domain?

Tags: html, web, dns

This is potentially a very stupid question and i'm likely to word it terrible so please be kind. I was wondering how some sites have pages before the domain, i.e. if my domain is 'www.example.com' then some sites have pages at url's such as 'test.example.com' could anyone tell me how i'd create a page like this?

(A real world example would be that the domain 'http://lolesports.com/' has the page 'http://euw.lolesports.com/')

Comment: It's not a page. It's a _subdomain_. How to get one depends on basically all the same factors that you considered when you set up your domain in the first place. This is basic stuff, so please consider doing more background research before opening questions. Anyway, StackOverflow is for programming, not server configuration, so head over to the sister site ServerFault if you still have questions after brushing up on web domain management.

Comment: That's not a "page", that's called a subdomain, and it should be created via whatever dashboard you manage your domain's DNS records with.

Comment: This is about DNS configurations more than programming. Those sites use subdomains.

Comment: Its called a subdomain https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdomain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are not pages, they are called *subdomains*. You should ask your web hosting provider how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is not a web page, it's a *subdomain*. A subdomain does not depend on your server but on the registrar of the URL.

To do that, you need to get an URL and see with your registrar how to set up a subdomain.